# Only Adding 1 Line to DB Then Skips the Rest

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to put a 2D array into a database. My code is as follows (this is PHP):

```
public function addspot($linearray,$data){
    $dbname=$data['dbname'];
    try {
        /* Create a connections with the supplied values */
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . Config::read('hostname') . ";dbname=" . Config::read('database'). "", Config::read('username'), Config::read('password'), array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        /* If any errors echo the out and kill the script */
        return 'Database conncetion fail in assets/garage.class.php!Make sure your database information is correct';
    }

    foreach ($linearray as $lines) {
        $spot="INSERT INTO `$dbname`(`floor`, `spot`, `status`, `uid`, `type`, `time`) VALUES ('$lines[0]', '$lines[1]', '$lines[2]', '$lines[3]', '$lines[4]', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($spot);
        if($statement->execute()){
            //silent
        } else {
            return 'Spot not added!';
        }
    }
}
```

The config values are being read correctly, as well as the statement to add a spot is correct.
I know this because when I run the function it correctly adds 1 "spot" but not the rest of the rows in my 2D array.

My array is as follows:

```
array (size=16)
0 => 
array (size=5)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
1 => 
array (size=5)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
 (and onwards)
```

My issue is that the function I have written only writes the first line (line[0]) to the database and the other ones do not get written.

**Update**
Output (using print_r) of statements:
Placed after the prepare

```
PDOStatement Object
(
[queryString] => INSERT INTO `Garage2`(`floor`, `spot`, `status`, `uid`, `type`, `time`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '0', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
)
PDOStatement Object
(
[queryString] => INSERT INTO `Garage2`(`floor`, `spot`, `status`, `uid`, `type`, `time`) VALUES ('1', '2', '1', '0', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
)
```

print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); output
Placed in the else (fail) part of the execute statement

```
Array
(
[0] => 00000
[1] => 
[2] => 
)
```

Comment: *font*, *small*, *b*, *i* ?? the 90's called and wants its html back - please learn css and modern html

Comment: @Dagon Thats XDebug...for those who use PHP in the 21st century :P I'll remove it's formatting

Comment: Why are you using `prepare` when you are not using bound parameters? That would also get rid of the multiple unneeded prepares that are happening (not automatically though). Note `PDO` is not something magic you can use to replace your `mysql_*` code as is.

Comment: @PeeHaa If I do not I get Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: @PeeHaa I don't use mysql. Never have. Its been deprecated, so I never even bothered with it.

Comment: mate, try using PDO::errorInfo and add the output to your question

Comment: @Tivie The native driver, obviously.

Comment: @PeeHaa Here, have a sarcastic cookie. Obviously I thought OP meant the RDBMS itself... Anyway, chriscct7 did you try using $pdo->errorInfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.
For those who run into this problem in the future, be sure to check that if you have a primary key on your DB, you are not using the same value twice. My first cell was my primary ID, and thus when the first and second statements both had 1 as the value, it failed.

To find this, I added this right after my prepare()\

```
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
```

Comment: That's a table design smell. For numeric primary IDs it's better to use auto increment. Primary IDs do have to be unique. However, you can use Indexes or composed indexes that don't need to be unique.

Comment: @Tivie What I want is that I know the first column will either contain the number 1-9, as will the second column. Trying to find a way to make the database automatically sort by lowest first, and lowest second.

Comment: PrimaryID won't serve that purpose. You can't "sort a database", but you can sort the results obtained from a query to a database.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick using prepared statements,
see if it works and drop me a message then i`ll format the answer better

```
$spot="INSERT INTO `$dbname`(`floor`, `spot`, `status`, `uid`, `type`, `time`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($spot);
foreach ($linearray as $lines) {
    $values = array($lines[0],$lines[1],$lines[2],$lines[3],$lines[4])
    if($statement->execute($values)){
        //silent
    }
    else {
        return 'Spot not added!';
    }
```

Comment: Solved already (primary key issue: see below). Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

For numeric primary IDs it's better to use auto increment. Primary IDs do have to be unique. However, you can use Indexes or composed indexes that don't need to be unique.

To answer your question regarding sorting your results, try this query:

```
-- Ordering by floor and spot
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY floor, spot;

-- Ordering by floor only
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY floor;
```

Here's a

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45bc3)**

---

note: The lines prepended by -- (double dash) are comments. You can remove them